# Wordpress caching CSS even when forcing filename

Tags: css, wordpress, caching

I have been away from Wordpress for a while (thankfully) but have had to come back for it as I have taken over a few builds that were made in it.

I am creating a few custom plugins for functionality on the page and am having trouble getting my CSS change to take affect. They are being cached  by the looks of things. This is not a theme's default CSS file this is a custom ones I am including.
I have forced the CSS file to be downloaded anew each time by appending URL variables to the CSS 'link' element href but this is not making a difference either.

When I examine the CSS it looks like the following:

```
    #slideshow-main {
    width:100%;
    height:400px;
}
#slideshow-main ul {
    width:100%;
    max-width:1170px;
    background-color:blue;
}�������������������������������������������������������������
```

Does Wordpress have other ways of caching the CSS? IT is starting to get rather frustrating!!!

Thanks

Comment: It is maybe server-related... wordpress does not cache.

Comment: I am running the Wordpress installation from a vagrant box on nGinx if that helps.

Comment: Check your nginx conf, it may try to load static file directly.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually a setting on my nGinx configuration.

In your nginx config (usally /etc/nginx/nginx.conf) or vhost config file change the sendfile parameter to off:

sendfile  off;

This worked for me.